# My shifter is not moving my gears

Tags: shifter, derailleur-front

My shifter is moving the cables but is not moving the derailer up or down and it is not moving the gears this is my  front gears

Comment: Can you move the front derailleur by hand? It's quite common for them to corrode (rust) when they are not moved regularly and left outside.

Comment: Is the cable moving everywhere in its path, or just at the shifter?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the cable has become detached from the derailleur, or has snapped.

Check the cable attachment at the derailleur. The pinch bolt that holds the cable may have come loose and the cable pulled through without becoming completely detached.

Before re-securing the cable, shift to the lowest gear position to pay out the maximum amount of cable, pull the cable taught, check the cable run to make sure the housing is properly seated in the shifter and all the stops on the frame.

While the cable is detached check that the derailleur can move by carefully pushing the cage with your hands. The spring is quite stiff so expect to use some force.

if the cable has snapped - possibly inside a section of housing - it will be loose. Pull on an exposed section of cable and this will be obvious.